# Assert mocked function called with json string in python

Tags: python, json, magicmock

Writing some unit tests in python and using MagicMock to mock out a method that accepts a JSON string as input. In my unit test, I want to assert that it is called with given arguments, however I run into issues with the assert statement, since the ordering of objects within the dict doesn't matter, besides in the assert statement for the string. Simplified example of what I am trying to achieve below.

```
mock_funct = MagicMock()
# mocked function called elsewhere
expected = {"a":"a", "b":"b"}
mock_funct.assert_called_once_with(json.dumps(expected))
```

The above may pass or may fail due to the arbitrary ordering of the keys within the dict when it is dumped to json, ie both `'{"a":"a", "b":"b"}'` and `'{"b":"b", "a":"a"}'` are valid dumps but one would fail and one would pass, however I would like to write the test so that either would pass.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll need to do your own checking here.  You can get the calls from the mock via it's `call_args_list` attribute (or, simply [`call_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) in this case since you have already asserted that it is called only once).  I'll assume you're using `unittest` in my example code -- but it should be easy enough to adapt for any testing framework ...

```
mock_funct.assert_called_once_with(mock.ANY)
call = mock_funct.call_args
call_args, call_kwargs = call  # calls are 2-tuples of (positional_args, keyword_args)
self.assertEqual(json.loads(call_args[0]), expected)
```

I've still used `assert_called_once_with` to make sure that the function was only called once with a single positional argument, but then [I open up the call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.call) to look at that argument to check that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood unittest's `assert_called_once_with` will perform equality checks on each argument in the call.

Python has a dunder method for controlling how equality checking is performed: [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

Knowing this we can create a wrapper class to help us:

```py
import json 

class JsonChecker:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return json.loads(other) == self.value

mock_funct.assert_called_once_with(JsonChecker(expected))
```